# How to add a fade effect to html transition with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, transition

I have this code (see jsfiddle below)

`<script type='text/javascript'>`
https://jsfiddle.net/mA8hj/ and would like to know how to edit the javascript in a way that by clicking the links in the fiddle, the text displayed fades slowly to another text when clicking another link. (Something like you'd use in CSS by adding -ms-transition: .2s;).

Thanks!

Comment: Is this what you want? https://jsfiddle.net/mA8hj/93/

Comment: You can simply use CSS class based transition. See my answer below.

Comment: Please do not insert useless code fragments in your question just to satisfy Stackoverflow's requirements. Post **meaningful code** . There is a reason for the requirement, and you're posting rubbish code only as a workaround that requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to pass `"slow"/"fast"/"medium"/any delay in milliseconds` as a parameter to `show`,

```
$('[class^="question"]').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var numb = this.className.replace('question', '');
    $('[id^="answer"]').hide();
    $('#answer' + numb).stop().show("slow");
});
```

### [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/mA8hj/)

Or by using `.fadeIn()`

```
$('[class^="question"]').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var numb = this.className.replace('question', '');
    $('[id^="answer"]').hide();
    $('#answer' + numb).css("opacity",0).stop().fadeIn("slow");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a CSS class and CSS transitions instead, and use jQuery only to add/remove this class `.show`:

```js
$('[class^="question"]').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var numb = this.className.replace('question', '');
    $('[id^="answer"]').removeClass("show");
    $('#answer' + numb).addClass("show");
});
```

```css
#answer,
#answer1,
#answer2,
#answer3,
#answer4 {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  transition-duration: 0.4s;
}
#answer.show,
#answer1.show,
#answer2.show,
#answer3.show,
#answer4.show {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="new_member_box"> 
    <a href="#" class="question1"><h4>Vision</h4></a>
</div>

<div class="new_member_box"> 
    <a href="#" class="question2"><h4>Church History</h4></a>
</div>

<div class="new_member_box"> 
    <a href="#" class="question3"><h4>Becoming a Member</h4></a>
</div>
<div class="new_member_box"> 
    <a href="#" class="question4"><h4>Pastor-in-Training</h4></a>
</div>

<div class="clear" class="question"></div>

<div id="answer1">1</div>
<div id="answer2">2</div>
<div id="answer3">3</div>
<div id="answer4">4</div>

<div class="new_member_box_display show" id="answer">Text will appear here when one of the tabs above is clicked</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/mA8hj/94/